# Prove that $B_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ where $\{A_n\}$ is an infinite sequence of events implies that $\{B_n\}$ is monotone decreasing.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

**Let $\Omega$ be a sample space and let $A_1, \, A_2, \, \dots$ be events. Define $B_n = \bigcup_{i=n}^{\infty} A_i$. Show that $B_1 \supset B_2 \supset \dots$**

So far, I have tried to use weak induction to prove this statement; however, I can't come up with an inductive hypothesis. I prove that the statement works for the base case:

\begin{equation}
B_1 = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \bigcup_{i=2}^{\infty} A_i \cup A_1= B_2 \cup A_1 \Longrightarrow B_1 \supset B_2.
\end{equation}

And I also showed that it also worked for n = k:

\begin{equation}
B_k = \bigcup_{i=k}^{\infty} A_i = \bigcup_{i=k+1}^{\infty} A_i \cup A_k = B_{k+1} \cup A_k \Longrightarrow B_k \supset B_{k+1}.
\end{equation}

But I have no inductive hypothesis, so I'm fairly certain something's wrong with the proof. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you see intuitively why it must be true? see that first, and then produce a proof.

Comment: Ismt this kind of obvious from definition of decreasing for sequence of sets? You do not need induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any inductive hypothesis here. This is just by definition -- not the one which you gave in the title, which is incorrect.

Set
$$B_n = \cup_{i=n}^\infty A_i.$$

What is $B_1$? $B_1$ is contains any element that is in $A_1$ or $A_2$ or $A_3$ or ...

What is $B_2$? $B_2$ contains any element that is in $A_2$ or $A_3$ or ...

Logically, $B_1$ contains all of $B_2$ AND $A_1$. So in particular $B_2 \subset B_1$.

This holds for all sets. If you want a "proof", suppose $\omega \in B_n$ for some $n$. We want to show that $\omega \in B_{n-1}$. Since $\omega \in B_n$, $\omega \in A_i$ for some $i \geq n$. Then $i \geq n-1$, so $A_i \subset B_{n-1}$. Therefore, $\omega \in B_{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks. That last paragraph was what I needed. I was making things too complicated.