# Induction argument for proving set relations without using the induction hypothesis. Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, induction

I'm a bit rusty in writing proofs. My argument looks correct, but I am a bit uncertain.

---

Let $\Omega$ be a sample space and $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ be events. Define:
$$
B_n = \bigcup_{i=n}^\infty A_i.
$$
Prove that $B_1\supset B_2\supset\ldots$.

**Proof**.
We will use an induction argument. First note that:
$$
B_1 = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = A_1\cup\left(\bigcup_{i=2}^\infty A_i\right)\supset \bigcup_{i=2}^\infty A_i = B_2 \;\;\;\Longrightarrow\;\;\; B_1\supset B_2 
$$
Assuming this is true for $k$, that is, $B_{k-1}\supset B_k$. Showing that it applies to $B_{k+1}$.
$$
B_k = \bigcup_{i=k}^\infty A_i = A_k\cup\left(\bigcup_{i=k+1}^\infty A_i\right)\supset \bigcup_{i=k+1}^\infty A_i = B_{k+1} \;\;\;\Longrightarrow\;\;\; B_k\supset B_{k+1} 
$$
By induction, we have proved that  $B_1\supset B_2\supset\ldots$ $\blacksquare$

---

I don't really use the induction hypothesis in the second step, so induction might be unnecessary? But at the same time, I feel it might not be correct to just prove it for some arbitrary $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and conclude that it is true for all $B_i$.

**Edit**
I also found this in the related posts section which is the same question.
[Prove that $B_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ where $\{A_n\}$ is an infinite sequence of events implies that $\{B_n\}$ is monotone decreasing.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625508/prove-that-b-n-bigcup-i-1-infty-a-i-where-a-n-is-an-infinite-seq?rq=1)

Comment: I don't see the need for induction. The key observation is to prove that $$B_k=A_k\cup B_{k+1}$$The rest follows naturally

Comment: There I go overcomplicating things again. Thanks for the reply!